# Marshal a double char pointer return value

Tags: c#, c, interop

A C library I'm using has a function which returns a pointer to an array of char pointers:

```c
extern char** getIds();
```

The example of use:

```c
char **list, **list_save;
list_save = list = getIds();
while (list && *list)
{
    printf("Id: %s\n", *list);
    list++;
}
freeIds(list_save);
```

Where `freeIds` is also from the C library, and frees the memory allocated during `getIds`.

They provide a .Net Interop assembly too, but it doesn't import the `getIds` function. I have access to the interop assembly source code.

My program is in C# so I'd like to know if it possible to add a import to the interop assembly and what it should look like, as well as what my C# code must look like to call the function.

My guess for the dll import is:

```cs
[DllImport("foo.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr getIds();
```

But I haven't been able to get C# to call it, therefore I don't know if the dll import is correct.

Comment: I am far from expert in interop, but I have a feeling there should be a way to marshal the array of char pointers as a `string[]`.

Comment: Note: You will have to export `freeIds` too, else you have a memory leak.

Comment: "I haven't been able" is not an appropriate problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Marshaling char**](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries#Marshaling_char.2A.2A). Your dllimport should work.